# tweepy collect twitter hashtag stream to csv file

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I am trying to run this script to collect streaming tweets realtime of a specific hashtag and save them in a csv file. This is the script I currently have. it prints to console and creates a csv file with author,date,text rows. the streamed tweets do not get saved to the csv however.

```
import sys
import tweepy
import csv

#pass security information to variables
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""


#use variables to access twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#create an object called 'customStreamListener'


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

def on_status(self, status): 
    print status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text
    with open('file.csv', 'w') as f: 
                f.write('Author,Date,Text')
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow([status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text])


def on_error(self, status_code):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
    return True # Don't kill the stream

def on_timeout(self):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
    return True # Don't kill the stream




streamingAPI = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
streamingAPI.filter(track=['russia'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a global variable writer outside the on_status.

For example (using your code)

```
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
global writer
        writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w+'))
        w.writerow(('Author', 'Date', 'Text'))
def on_status(self, status): 
    print status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text
    writer.writerow(status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text)
```